# how to make bold textview android japanese character

Tags: android, textview

i know to make `bold textview -> android:textStyle="bold"` , but it didn't happen in Japanese Character. So any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In your res/values/strings.xml

You can try this idea

```
<string name="some_japanese">
<![CDATA[<b>日本</b>
  ]]>
</string>
```

And get it to

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.some_japanese)));
```