# Foreign characters (japanese) not getting bold on textview

Tags: android, textview

The jap chars comes from server as json so this [how to make bold textview android japanese character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357632/how-to-make-bold-textview-android-japanese-character) doesn't apply to me.

I tried the following but to no avail.

```
title.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);

android:textStyle="bold"

title.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + data.getBookTitle() + "</b>"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still can't bold it, but you can achieve a somewhat the same approach through the use of shadows in the xml, just add these to your textviews, edit the values to your liking.

This also applies to most foreign characters, not just jap chars.

```
android:shadowColor="#000000"
android:shadowDx="0.1"
android:shadowDy="0.1"
android:shadowRadius="0.5"
```